# ApplyProvisioningTemplate function from SharepointPnPCoreOnline is taking too much time to create a site using a XML Template

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-dev-pnp

I'm currently working with the SharepointPnPCoreOnline library, or more specifically, with the git project Sharepoint/PnP-Sites-Core. I'm using it to download the XML template of a site:

```
ProvisioningTemplate template = web.GetProvisioningTemplate();
```

and then applying the template to a new site with:

```
web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template);
```

It seems to be doing its job (although it's having some issues applying the exact content types) and it completes the task without critical errors. The problem is that it is taking a long time to create the whole site (an average of 90 minutes ).

The template contains the next components:

- no subsites
- 21 PropertyBagEntry
- 21 NavigationNode
- 20 ListInstance

Each List Instance has an average of:

- 4 ContentTypeBinding
- 4 View (Each view with 13 FieldRef)
- 8 Field
- 49 FieldRef

Here you can see part of the [Debug log](https://gist.github.com/Luis-Art-Guerra/56ea35975ab164b33c1a6af43331f21a).
Each list creation takes from 30 to 40 seconds to complete. 
Updating field references is faster (2 seconds each approx.), but there seems to be a lot of them.

Right now we are using wsp files to apply the templates, but it seems this option will stop being supported for Sharepoint Online (i don't know when exactly), that's why we are testing this method. If these are normal execution times for the SharepointPnPCoreOnline library, is there any other method we could use to apply the templates to a Sharepoint Online Site?

Thank you very much for your time.